# Get video info during download with youtube-dl embedded in python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm embedding youtube-dl into my python code to download a video such as below.

```
ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': f'%(id)s.%(ext)s',
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'forcejson': 'forcejson',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '128',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    status = ydl.download([youtube_link])
print(status) # Returns 0 if successful
```

It downloads fine, and returns `status`, which is 0 when successful.

But I then need to also get some video info, like duration, title, author, etc.  Youtube-dl gets this during download, and I can force it to print using `forcejson` opt.  But how can I get it so I can store it in a variable as well, without having to run it again using `ydl.extract_info(youtube_link)` (which downloads the webpage again and takes 10-20 seconds sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `download=False` to avoid downloading the video.

```
def extract_info(self, url, download=True, ie_key=None, extra_info={},
                 process=True, force_generic_extractor=False):
    '''
    Returns a list with a dictionary for each video we find.
    If 'download', also downloads the videos.
    extra_info is a dict containing the extra values to add to each result
    '''
```